# What algorithm can I use to count how many students have the same score?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, pass-by-reference

I am currently learning about pointers in my C++ class. The following code was slightly confusing but I eventually got it, my current problem is my logic.

I'm told I can find the number of students that have the same score without sorting or searching and using a single index but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I have scores stored in scoresArray and the element number identifys which student it belongs to.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int maxStudents = 30;
void readScores(double[]);
void gradeCounter(double[],int&,int&,int&,int&,int&);
void sameScore(double[]);

int main()
{
    int As = 0, Bs = 0, Cs = 0, Ds = 0, Fs = 0; // Distribution of scores

    double scoreArray[maxStudents];
    readScores(scoreArray);
    gradeCounter(scoreArray, As, Bs, Cs, Ds, Fs);

   system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}


void readScores(double scoreArray[])
{
    double *scorePTR;
    scorePTR = scoreArray;

    for(int count = 0; count < maxStudents; count++)
    {
        cout<<"Please enter score for student "<<count+1<<" or -999 to end.\n";
        cin>>*(scorePTR+count);
        if(*(scorePTR+count) == -999)
        break;
    }
}


void gradeCounter(double scoreArray[],int &As,int &Bs,int &Cs,int &Ds,int &Fs)
{
double *scorePTR2;
scorePTR2 = scoreArray;

    for(int count = 0; count < maxStudents; count++)
    {
        if(scoreArray[count] >= 90)
            As+=1;
        else if(*(scorePTR2+count) >= 80 && *(scorePTR2+count) < 90)
            Bs+=1;      
        else if(*(scorePTR2+count) >= 70 && *(scorePTR2+count) < 80)
            Cs+=1;
        else if(*(scorePTR2+count) >= 60 && *(scorePTR2+count) < 70)
            Ds+=1;
        else if(*(scorePTR2+count) >= 0 && *(scorePTR2+count) < 60)
            Fs+=1;
    }
}

void sameScore(double scoreArray[])
{

}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the answer, *(scorePTR+count) is the same as scorePTR[count]

Comment: May I *please* retag this as `[c]`?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do based on your explanation.  But if you are given a number of students with scores that can range from 0 - 100.  You can use bucket sort of find out how many students have the same score.  Just create an array with a size of 101.  For each student with a particular score, add 1 to the array slot of the same index.  At the end, look in your array and add up the values of all the elements that have values large than 1.  That is the number of students that have the same scores.  This requires no sorting and runs in O(n).

Answer (score 4):

You can create a second array of 101 elements (from 0 to 100), initialize it all to 0, and use the current student's score as the index into this array

So, if the current student has a score of 87, then you would increment this_new_array[87] by 1.

In the end, the array at index X will contain the number of students that have score X.

Comment: How would I take the score 87 say in element 1 and let the compiler know I want it to point to new_array[87]?

Comment: What I mean is, I know how to access the scoreArray, I would use a for loop to go through it and to read each score.  What I don't get is, how do I take the score and let the compiler know I want to increment the element that matches that score.

Comment: this_new_array[scoreArray[count]]++

Comment: @BojinLi When I try this I get a red squiggly under scoreArray and it says  "expression must have integral or enum type"

Comment: That means your scoreArray is float or double (which it is...). This method only works if all of your scores are integers (ie whole numbers). If you allow one decimal place for instance, you can multiply the score by 10 and still use the same method.